# Adjust pivot point programmatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have found [this](http://orbcreation.com/orbcreation/page.orb?1099) extension which might be able to adjust the pivot point of a GameObject (Text) programmatically.

My question is: How do I implement it? Can someone explain step by step? I don't see any instructions in the site...

[image: Unity Editor Screenshot]

Comment: I'm going to guess you need to change the [GameObject.transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) property.

Comment: @MattBurland There is no pivot point property.

Comment: @MattBurland Please remove the duplicate banner. The question has been edited.

Comment: Please ensure you understand the [fundamentals of C# extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx) before posing further questions.